# Inconsistent behaviour when exporting PPID to the environment on NixOS

Tags: bash, environment-variables, distributions

In bash I tried to export `PPID` as an environment variable.  But the results look very inconsistent to me, across different Linux distributions.

On Ubuntu 18.04 *most* of the commands below work "as expected".  On NixOS I get the following behaviour:

```bsh
# normally PPID is not part of the environment
env | grep PPID
# --> no output

# exporting for a single command does not work
PPID=foo some-command
# --> bash: PPID: readonly variable

# exporting "works" (it does not print an error)
export PPID
# and the variable seems to be part of the environment
env | grep PPID
# --> PPID=12345
awk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["PPID"]; exit}'
# --> 12345
# but some external commands don't see it!
python -c 'import os; print(os.environ.get("PPID"))'
# --> None on NixOS // 12345 on Ubuntu
nvim --headless -u NONE -i NONE -c 'echo $PPID' -c quit
# --> *no output* (on NixOS and Ubuntu)

# using env to export it explicitly, so bash will not complain,
# "works" as good as `export PPID` above, but does not produce 
# the "readonly variable" error message
env PPID=foo awk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["PPID"]; exit}'
# -> foo
env PPID=foo python -c 'import os; print(os.environ.get("PPID"))'
# --> None // foo on Ubuntu
```

If I change the name of the environment variable to something other (which is not special in bash) like `PARENT_PROCESS` it works as expected on both distributions and with all commands I tested.

Can anybody explain what is going on here?

---

Versions on NixOS unstable (`21.03pre244045.1179840f9a8 (Okapi)`):

- bash: `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)` from `/nix/store/xadrr3l5jvkkm3g3lb2g81j5wz51zqdv-bash-interactive-4.4-p23/bin/bash`
- libc: `/nix/store/9df65igwjmf2wbw0gbrrgair6piqjgmi-glibc-2.31/lib/libc-2.31.so`

Versions on Ubuntu 18.04:

- bash: `GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` from package `bash` version `4.4.18-2ubuntu1.2`
- libc: 2.27 from package `libc6` version `2.27-3ubuntu1.2`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I don't think it makes much sense to export `PPID`, since it is supposed to reflect the parent process id of the current shell, and this value changes for each shell. If you want the process id of a particular process, like the grandparent of the python process in your example, why don't you do what you suggested yourself: assign the value of `PPID` to `PARENT_PROCESS` and read that in your subprocess?

Comment: @JohanMyréen yes I want to know to grandparent id. I am using this in [a pager I am writing](https://github.com/lucc/nvimpager) to detect if it is run from man or git: https://github.com/lucc/nvimpager/blob/148499570bb203f00512239118716b78d70f4eaf/lua/nvimpager.lua#L233-L255 
But for this I will soon change the name of the variable. It just did work on most systems up until now.

But with this question I mainly just want to learn what is going on here. Why does it behave the way it  does? Where are the relevant differences (because I did not see them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PPID` variable is a special shell variable (not an environment variable) that reflects the value of the parent process id. The value can be exported into the environment, but if it is passed to a subshell, the subshell creates a new `PPID` shell variable, and removes `PPID` from the list of variables to be exported to a subprocess.

The difference in behavior between different operating systems or distributions is explained by that in some the subprocesses are invoked via wrapper shell scripts, in others not. If a wrapper script is used, the intermediate shell removes `PPID` from the environment, but if the final process (Python or nvim) is executed directly the `PPID` variable is still in the environment.